# Neutral wire is tied to my electric metal box, why is it so?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding, neutral

[image][image]I have this old Depard switch box in my patio.

Originally, I wanted to 'add' a receptacle in my old Despard switch 'array' stack. Now I am puzzled and afraid of doing that because I found out that the original 'neutral' wire was tied/screwed to the electrical metal box, and of course, there was no ground wire installed.

Some outlets in my house are not grounded. (though I see long tails grounded wires coming off the house to the pipes outside of my house). I just don't know why isn't the entire house grounded.

Q1: Is it safe if I just leave the 'neutral' wire screwed to the box like before? (because I am afraid that I couldn't install a receptacle)

Q2: If I wire the 'neutral'(silver) and 'hot' (gold) to the new receptacle (bottom position), will it work?

Q3: If Q2's answer is yes, then do I need to ground the new switch?

Q4: Should I wrap that lonely neutral wire so it won't touch the metal box?  I just couldn't figure out why would my previous owner 'ground' a neutral wire?

Thank you very much. right now, unless I fully understand what is going on, I don't want to install anything. My house is old, I don't want to start a fire.

[image]

Here is the inside of the switch box.
[image]

Comment: “Patio” is a location that’s likely to require GFCI for any outlet.  In the era despard was popular they did many weird things, for example,  California 3-ways were very popular.  I’ve never heard of “neutral grounding the box” but that well could have been one of the strange concepts of that era.  Despard stacks are also hard to work with based on the number of conductors and box fill.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/xDUs8uiTQhijL6mN8

Comment: I'm using my cell phone. Haven't figure our how to upload a photo yet. The patio is now covered by all around glass doors and used as a room full of light. :D. (storage room actually)

Comment: Can you give us a photo that looks into the back of the box?

Comment: color coding *alone* is not meaningful.  We would to see how cables (groups of 2-4 wires) enter the box, and which groups go where, and if wires are tied together in the back of the box that don't actually go to the switches.

Comment: My guess is that the white is a true neutral. Someone installing the switches (which is Hot one side, 2 Switched Hots on the other) didn't know what to do with the neutral and thought "neutral = ground at the main box so screwed it to the box like a ground here. If that is correct then it should have been capped with a wire nut. As far as no ground wire, that is quite common and if there is metal conduit from the box back to the main panel then that would provide the ground path.

Comment: I am away from my house. I will take a shot at the 'inside' of the ugly box. :)  My impression is that there is no other group of wires except a hot wire connected to the top switch lefthand side, then a pigtail coming out that lefthand into the 2nd switch (hot continues to that switch).  Then, two switches all go out to their light fixtures. I have two lightings serving the 'patio'.  Since I noticed the white wire is 'screwed' to the screw hole of my metal box, I am really scared of it since I have never seen such a thing in the past.  I have 'capped' it for now. Light still works now. :D

Comment: Dear all.. I've taken the inside shot of the switch box. 4 wires in total:
1) hot (black, if you can see, old dusty black)
2) white neutral (used to be tied to the box screw)
3) two very dark red for two lights

That is all.  I've tested the voltage:
When the switch is in 'off' position. Fuse box is turned on.
Black - white: 118
Black - 1st red - 106 ~ 83 (seems to be an up/down cycle)
Black - 2nd red - 83 (seems to steadly remain in this number)

Comment: White - Wall - 0
Black - Wall: 117

Based on the above test, I'd assume that the 'grounded' neutral is a real neutral.  That's all I know so far. :D

Answer (score 1):

### I would use the white as a neutral

Based on what we can tell so far, the white is indeed a neutral wire, so that should be wired up to the silver screw on the outlet, with the brass screw on the outlet connected to a pigtail to the existing black hot, which is also pigtailed to the switches.  It definitely should not be landed on the box, though!

### And run a separate ground wire

From there, you can then run a separate ground wire (green #12 THHN or bare #12 copper works, provided it's not subject to physical damage) back to a suitable grounding point (i.e. another suitably sized equipment grounding wire, the wire that connects the panel to the grounding electrode system, or back to the panel, but *not* to a water pipe) to ground the box and receptacle.

### As to the rest of the improper grounds...

To clean up the rest of the improper grounds, what I would do is take some 6AWG bare copper and run it alongside your cold water pipe from the point where the water pipe is connected to the panel to the end of the water pipe run.  This will serve as an equipment grounding "busbar" or "trunk" of sorts.  Then, I would use an [Ilsco GTT-2-2 tap connector](http://www.electricsupplyinc.com/index.jsp?path=product&part=149112&ds=dept&process=search&qdx=0&ID=%2CFittings%2Cdept-1JO) to connect the grounding electrode/bonding conductor (the wire from your water pipe to the panel) to your grounding bus wire -- the part that comes off and goes back on lets you slip the existing wire in there without having to cut it and splice it back together, while your new wire can go in the other hole, and both screws can get tightened down then.  From there, you can use *split bolts*, or a similar sort of tap connector, to connect your existing grounding bus wire to the improper ground wires after disconnecting them from however they were attached to the water pipe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know of your opinion on this:

1) If I don't want to add the outlet with the switches anymore.  Should I cap the neutral? It should be safer than leaving it attched/screwed to the box, right?
2) If I cap it, should I bother grounding it?
3) Also, another Q, why couldn't I ground it with a water pipe? (Omg, I did that on another outlet in my house.) I should remove it. right?
Thanks a million!!

Comment: To 1) and 2) cap the neutral if you aren't going to use it for a receptacle...as to 3) using water pipes as part of the equipment grounding system is bad because you can't rely on the next numpty not to slap a length of CPVC or PEX in to replace a busted pipe, messing up your grounding.  You'll want to run your grounding wires back to the fuse/breaker box, instead.

Comment: Thank you again. I will cap the neutral and leave them the way they were. Also, I will remove my ground wire tied to a water pipe. I will not use those outlets that have no groundings. (I have a tester that tells me if the outlet is grounded or not.) Safety first, especially for a 'non-electrician' kind of person. :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Handywomanwannabe -- the better solution is to extend those ground wires back to the breaker box whichever way you can.  Given that they're working as grounds, I wouldn't run around unhooking them straight away, but instead go through and fix them up to be proper.

Comment: hate to admit it - I have no idea how to run a wire back to the breaker box. I have a very old breaker box. I am even more afraid of touching the on/off switches.  I honestly believe they'll break one day. I need to educate myself before trying any daring thought of mine. It's interesting to learn but I am afraid of actually doing it. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: How about using those stakes that go down to the earth? I've seen those but wonder if they'd work for me (quick fix?) :D

Comment: @Handywomanwannabe -- no, ground electrodes do something totally different than a ground wire to the breaker box.  HOWEVER, if you can find the *wire* (Grounding Electrode Conductor) that connects your breaker box to the ground electrodes (ground stakes) for your house, you can tie your ground wires to *that*.

Comment: If the breakers are Federal Pacific brand, you have more problems.  Also, you can read the NEC at NFPA.org for free. There are also good DIY books in your library, online, and some of the big box stores.  Once you understand how neutrals and grounds are different, and how a multiwire one-neutral branch circuit works, you'll probably be safe set loose on rewiring.  Grounds wires are your friends,